# Spring XD Yarn: Stream runs only on exactly two containers

Tags: spring-xd

**Spring XD Yarn: Stream runs only on exactly two containers**

Spring XD Yarn ver 1.2.1 
1.In servers.yml, set no of containers to 15.(I have 16 Node managers in my YARN cluster)
2.All 15 containers are created. I confirmed this by executing 'runtime containers' in xd-shell
3.When I run a Spring XD stream from kafka source to hdfs sink, exactly only two containers(of the 15 containers) are used. The remaining 13 containers are not used. My stream runs for 6 to 7 hrs.In all this 6 hrs, only two of the 15 live containers are used for this stream.
4. Please let me know how to make my stream run on all 15 live containers.
     --> Is there any configuration that I missed, please do the needful.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the deployment manifest: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#deployment-manifest

You can use deployment properties to scale up your stream and control the module count - i.e. how many instances of each module are you deploying. I would suspect that your stream runs with the default of 1, which means that you are getting exactly one source module instance and one sink module instance. The default deployment algorithm would indeed deploy them on separate containers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius, got it.

Comment: Hi Satish, you're welcome! If you feel that this is a good answer, please vote so that others that are have the same issue can find it :)